# ¿Obtener bits o bytes correspondientes al código ASCII de un string?

Tags: java

Encontré este método en StackOverflow en ingles, pero, por ejemplo, para **"K"** me devuelve el byte **75**. Y según veo en internet el codigo ASCII en Hexadecimal de **"K"** es **4B**.
Este es el codigo:

```
String s = "K";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Comment: Pero entonces, lo que quieres es obtener el valor hexadecimal de esta tabla? [Tabla ASCII](https://ascii.cl/es/)

Comment: Correcto, eso es lo que necesito. O el binario también me sirve.

Comment: Es porque el método get bytes te devuelve el valor en decimal, sólo necesitas hacer una conversión a hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes convertir los bytes a Hexadecimal ya que bytes devuelve un valor deimal

```
String s = "K";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
System.out.println(bytesToHex(b));    


private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Puedes probar este codigo aqui: [Compilador de Java Online](http://rextester.com/l/java_online_compiler)

Comment: Deberias al menos citar la fuente y mencionar al autor cuando copias codigo ajeno: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/525826

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
String s = "K";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
String [] inHex= new String[bytes.length];
for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++) {
    inHex[i] = Integer.toHexString(bytes[i]);
}
```